# Append not thread-safe?

Tags: go, concurrency, append, slice, goroutine

I noticed that if I tried appending to a slice using goroutines inside a `for` loop, there would be instances where I would get missing/blank data:

```
destSlice := make([]myClass, 0)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, myObject := range sourceSlice {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(closureMyObject myClass) {
        defer wg.Done()
        var tmpObj myClass
        tmpObj.AttributeName = closureMyObject.AttributeName
        destSlice = append(destSlice, tmpObj)
    }(myObject)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Sometimes, when I print all `AttributeName`s from `destSlice`, some elements are empty strings (`""`), and other times, some elements from `sourceSlice` are not present in `destSlice`.

Does my code have a data race, and does this mean that `append` is not thread-safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Go no value is safe for concurrent read/write, slices (which are [slice headers](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader)) are no exception.

Yes, your code has data races. Run with the `-race` option to verify.

Example:

```
type myClass struct {
    AttributeName string
}
sourceSlice := make([]myClass, 100)

destSlice := make([]myClass, 0)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, myObject := range sourceSlice {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(closureMyObject myClass) {
        defer wg.Done()
        var tmpObj myClass
        tmpObj.AttributeName = closureMyObject.AttributeName
        destSlice = append(destSlice, tmpObj)
    }(myObject)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Running it with

```
go run -race play.go
```

Output is:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c420074000 by goroutine 6:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:20 +0x69

Previous write at 0x00c420074000 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:20 +0x106

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:21 +0x1cb

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:21 +0x1cb
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c42007e000 by goroutine 6:
  runtime.growslice()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:82 +0x0
  main.main.func1()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:20 +0x1a7

Previous write at 0x00c42007e000 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:20 +0xc4

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:21 +0x1cb

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:21 +0x1cb
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c420098120 by goroutine 80:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:20 +0xc4

Previous write at 0x00c420098120 by goroutine 70:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:20 +0xc4

Goroutine 80 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:21 +0x1cb

Goroutine 70 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:21 +0x1cb
==================
Found 3 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

Solution is simple, use a [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) to protect writing the `destSlice` value:

```
var (
    mu        = &sync.Mutex{}
    destSlice = make([]myClass, 0)
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, myObject := range sourceSlice {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(closureMyObject myClass) {
        defer wg.Done()
        var tmpObj myClass
        tmpObj.AttributeName = closureMyObject.AttributeName
        mu.Lock()
        destSlice = append(destSlice, tmpObj)
        mu.Unlock()
    }(myObject)
}
wg.Wait()
```

You could also solve it in other ways, e.g. you could use a channel on which you'd send the value to be appended, and have a designated goroutine receiving from this channel and do the append.

Also note that while slice headers are not safe, slice elements act as different variables and different slice elements can be written concurrently without synchronization (because they are distinct variables). See [Can I concurrently write different slice elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879322/can-i-concurrently-write-different-slice-elements/49879469#49879469)

Comment: > In Go no value is safe for concurrent read/write, slices (which are slice headers) are no exception.

False. See other answer that uses a slice to collect results from goroutines.

Comment: @raine No, it is true. Slice _elements_ and slice _header_ are **not** the same. Slice elements act as distinct variables, so they can be written concurrently without synchronization, but the slice header cannot. So a slice value (header) _is not_ safe for concurrent read and write! See [Can I concurrently write different slice elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879322/can-i-concurrently-write-different-slice-elements/49879469#49879469)

Answer (score 21):

It's quite an old question but there is another small improvement that helps to get rid of mutex. You can use index to add to array. Each go routine will use it's own index. In this case synchronization is not necessary.

```
destSlice := make([]myClass, len(sourceSlice))

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i, myObject := range sourceSlice {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(idx int, closureMyObject myClass) {
        defer wg.Done()
        var tmpObj myClass
        tmpObj.AttributeName = closureMyObject.AttributeName

        destSlice[idx] = tmpObj
     }(i, myObject)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a handy solution for when you know the size of your collections beforehand! Many thanks for sharing!

Comment: I like this solution a lot, and used it to fix my own problem. Thank you! I like it, that it doesn't require an import, and it also optimises a little bit, by allocating a fixed array instead of dynamically increasing it on appends.

Answer (score 6):

To give a more recent solution to this problem, it looks like Go has released a new map for sync purposes:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/syncmap

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it!

Answer (score 6):

Question has been answered, but my favorite way to solve this problem is with [errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup). One of the examples in the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#example-Group-Parallel) is this exact problem plus one nice addition the handling of errors.

Below is the meat of the example from the docs:

```
g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

searches := []Search{Web, Image, Video}
results := make([]Result, len(searches))
for i, search := range searches {
    i, search := i, search // https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines
    g.Go(func() error {
        result, err := search(ctx, query)
        if err == nil {
            results[i] = result
        }
        return err
    })
}
if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return results, nil
```

Hope this is helpful to those who are not aware of the errgroup package.