Access from multiple goroutines to a single array
I am studying Go at the moment with a practical purpose. I need to write a program in which I need to process an array containing several million Float values. In c++ this task is easily solved by creating a pointer and dividing indexes of all elements between several processing threads.
For example, I have an array [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x].
Thread number 1 will get the area from 0-1, thread number 2 the area from 2-3 and so on.  But only on a scale of several million, and the threads will be for example 16/32/64. Approximately the same principle as in CUDA.
Is it possible to do something similar in Go?
Thanks!
demo code:
import "fmt"
 
func main() {
   
    var numbers [10000000]float64= [10000000]float64{}
    //prepare numbers 

    f:= func(first int, last int){
      //magic is here (read/write)
    }
    
    go f(0, 999999) 
    go f(1000000, 1999999)
    and so on...

}

I'm just starting to learn

Yes, as long as the regions do not overlap, you can do this without a memory race.

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71413041/is-it-thread-safe-to-concurrently-read-access-an-array-in-go/71413123#71413123

Yes, you can do that. Here's one way, rather than passing in fixed ranges the workers do their own iteration. Note the use of sync.WaitGroup to ensure main waits for all workers to complete.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    const num_workers = 3
    var numbers = []int{1, 3, 5, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 100, 101, 103, 99, 55, 1039, 938}

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < num_workers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            for j := i; j < len(numbers); j += num_workers {
                fmt.Printf("worker: %d, input: %d\n", i, numbers[j])
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

Demonstration.
But the more idiomatic way in Go is to use a channel. Workers pull the numbers from the channel as needed.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    const num_workers = 3
    var numbers = []int{1, 3, 5, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 100, 101, 103, 99, 55, 1039, 938}

    inputs := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < num_workers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            for input := range inputs {
                fmt.Printf("worker: %d, input: %d\n", i, input)
            }
        }()
    }

    // main feeds the numbers into the channel.
    for _, num := range numbers {
        inputs <- num
    }

    // this allows `for input := range inputs` to exit
    // once the channel is empty
    close(inputs)

    wg.Wait()
}

This supports a changing number of workers, and workers can go at their own pace. The numbers do not need to be slurped into memory, the channel can be fed from a stream.
Demonstration

Thank you for your good answers. Just a question. Is the more idiomatic way better than the first one, even in the view of performance?

I wrote my guess based on my test. If you don't mind and have free time, please check it. :bow:

@nimdrak There is no "better", they are tools. While concurrency can be about performance, spreading the work across multiple processors, whether it will make things go faster depends on what's being done. Some problems cannot be divided up in the way you propose. Sometimes it's about reliability. For a trivial math problem the fastest way can be a single threaded loop.

I understand it depends on the situation but concurrency is also for improving performance. I agree with you. Thank you for sharing your insight :+1:

I'm moved by @Schwern's answer and I became curious about which one is better in the view of the performances.
So I tried writing the benchmark test for it.
I concluded the first one(not using channel) is better based on the benchmark test. I guess these can be reasons for the lower performance of using channel.

We need to initialize channel first.
Channel includes a kind of synchronization.

So, when we don't need a synchronization mechanism and consider the performance first, then not using channel can be a good choice.
The test I did
benchmark test result
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: stackoverflow/4_20_2
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Benchmark_WayToCalculate
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/More_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/More_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000-12               16218         73591 ns/op
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/MoreWithChan_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/MoreWithChan_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000-12       16784         71074 ns/op
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/Less_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/Less_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000-12              370484          3258 ns/op
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/More_:_workers=5,_inputSize=10000000
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/More_:_workers=5,_inputSize=10000000-12               2     727096374 ns/op
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/MoreWithChan_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000#01
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/MoreWithChan_:_workers=5,_inputSize=1000#01-12                    2     694149272 ns/op
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/Less_:_workers=5,_inputSize=10000000
Benchmark_WayToCalculate/Less_:_workers=5,_inputSize=10000000-12                         930       1293655 ns/op
PASS

caculcate.go
package calculate

import (
    "sync"
)

func doSomething(input int) int {
    return 2 * input
}

func MoreIdiomaticWay(workers int, inputs []int, _ chan int) {
    inputCh := make(chan int, len(inputs))
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for input := range inputCh {
                doSomething(input)
            }
        }()
    }

    for _, input := range inputs {
        inputCh <- input
    }

    close(inputCh)

    wg.Wait()
}

func MoreIdiomaticWayWithChan(workers int, inputs []int, inputCh chan int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for input := range inputCh {
                doSomething(input)
            }
        }()
    }

    for _, input := range inputs {
        inputCh <- input
    }

    close(inputCh)

    wg.Wait()
}

func LessIdiomaticWay(workers int, inputs []int, _ chan int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for worker := 0; worker < workers; worker++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        i := worker
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := i; j < len(inputs); j += workers {
                doSomething(inputs[j])
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}


caculcate_test.go
package calculate

import (
    "testing"
)

type calculate func(int, []int, chan int)

func generateInput(size int) []int {
    input := make([]int, size)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        input[i] = i
    }
    return input
}

func Benchmark_WayToCalculate(b *testing.B) {
    type scenario struct {
        name       string
        way        calculate
        workers    int
        inputSize  int
        useChannel bool
    }

    scenarios := []scenario{
        {
            name:      "More : workers=5, inputSize=1000",
            way:       MoreIdiomaticWay,
            workers:   5,
            inputSize: 1000,
        },
        {
            name:       "MoreWithChan : workers=5, inputSize=1000",
            way:        MoreIdiomaticWayWithChan,
            workers:    5,
            inputSize:  1000,
            useChannel: true,
        },
        {
            name:      "Less : workers=5, inputSize=1000",
            way:       LessIdiomaticWay,
            workers:   5,
            inputSize: 1000,
        },
        {
            name:      "More : workers=5, inputSize=10000000",
            way:       MoreIdiomaticWay,
            workers:   5,
            inputSize: 10000000,
        },
        {
            name:       "MoreWithChan : workers=5, inputSize=1000",
            way:        MoreIdiomaticWayWithChan,
            workers:    5,
            inputSize:  10000000,
            useChannel: true,
        },
        {
            name:      "Less : workers=5, inputSize=10000000",
            way:       LessIdiomaticWay,
            workers:   5,
            inputSize: 10000000,
        },
    }

    for _, s := range scenarios {
        input := generateInput(s.inputSize)
        b.Run(s.name, func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                var channel chan int
                if s.useChannel {
                    channel = make(chan int, s.inputSize)
                }

                b.StartTimer()
                s.way(s.workers, input, channel)
                b.StopTimer()
            }
        })
    }
}



Your doSomething is very trivial, the benchmark will emphasize the concurrency overhead. It's not a realistic use of concurrency.

You're right. this benchmark just emphasizes the concurrency load. Thank you for checking it! :bow:
