# Race condition for not yet existing object

Tags: go, race-condition

I've a strange race condition. The problem is that it occurs inside an object which is not existing yet.

Here is a demo code:

```
package main

import (
    //"fmt"
    "time"
)

type Object1 struct {
    A int
    B string
    C []int
    D *Object2
}

type Object2 struct {
    A int
}

func NewObject1() *Object1 {
    return &Object1{
        A: 1,
        B: "abc",
        C: []int{0, 1},
        D: &Object2{},
    }
}

func main() {
    list := []*Object1{}

    tempA := 0
    tempB := ""
    tempC := []int{}
    tempD := &Object2{}

    go func() {
        for {
            for _, object := range list {
                tempA = object.A
                tempB = object.B
                tempC = object.C
                tempD = object.D
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        list = append(list, NewObject1())

        //fmt.Println("list", list)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

If I run it with the `-race` flag - I get the warnings:

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000094040 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/race.go:39 +0x84

Previous write at 0x00c000094040 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:21 +0x2a9

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:36 +0x276
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000094048 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/race.go:40 +0xbe

Previous write at 0x00c000094048 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:22 +0x2ca

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:36 +0x276
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000094058 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/race.go:41 +0x118

Previous write at 0x00c000094058 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:23 +0x341

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:36 +0x276
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000094070 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /tmp/race.go:42 +0x180

Previous write at 0x00c000094070 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:24 +0x3b8

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /tmp/race.go:36 +0x276
==================
```

But how is that possible? Reading happens inside a goroutine and writing inside a `NewObject1()`. 4 errors for every `Object1` field. `NewObject1()` has not created an object yet to append it to the `list` slice. So `list` during the reading should be empty or filled with a normal completed objects.

Step by step workflow in my mind:

1. list is empty;
2. you start to create new `object1`;
3. list is still empty;
4. you have created a new object and only then add it to the list;
5. only now list has 1 element;
6. reading happens.

I don't see a race condition here. If you think differently - please show your own workflow of how things happens.

Comment: "has not created an object yet" --- you don't have synchronisation in your code, so there is no "happens-after" relationship established between different parts of your code, hence you cannot reason about temporal aspects of events in runtime.

Comment: @Flimzy, because `NewObject1()` is creating/returning a new fresh object and it can't be used somewhere else before is created. `NewObject1()` is only creating it at that moment, isn't it?

Comment: If you think differently - please explain more technically detailed

Comment: @Flimzy, yes, but goroutine shouldn't be able to read an object which is not created yet?! Question is about race condition. Step by step workflow in my mind - 1) list is empty. 2) you start to create new object1. 3) list is still empty. 4) you have created a new object and only then add it to the list. 5) only now list has 1 element. 6) reading happens. Where you see a race condition?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152988/append-not-thread-safe

Comment: @Flimzy, write your workflow which shows a race. Step by step. `yet` is BEFORE you add an element to the list

Comment: @Alexey it does not happen BEFORE, but AFTER you added an element to the slice.

Comment: @mkopriva even if it was thread-safe there still would be a data race.

Comment: @zerkms, you mean empty struct is created first, added to the list, and only after that it's fields are being filled/written??

Comment: @Alexey you don't synchronise access to memory, there are no any guarantees. It makes no sense to discuss a data race: the behaviour is undefined and cannot be reasoned about.

Comment: I just wish to understand. It seems that fields writing happens AFTER the struct is added to the list. Is that possible? Because I didn't want that in my code

Comment: @Alexey you cannot tell when write **actually happened**

Comment: @zerkms, by 'it seems' I mean what race detector shows. This is a little confusing

Comment: @Alexey race detector only shows you have non-synchronised read and write operations. It tells nothing about whether any data was written there by that moment or not. It only checks memory addresses, it does not care about the actual operations progress.

Comment: @Alexey: just as zerkms says, data race situation is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. From corrupted data to [nuclear missile launch](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong). Synchronize your reads and writes.

Comment: @zerkms I was only trying to point out that rather than focusing on `NewObject1` and the `temp` variable assignments, the issue can be fixed by synchronizing the read/write of the slice. E.g. this https://play.golang.org/p/60bevT89WFf doesn't trigger the race messages.

Comment: Your proper work flow is: 1. list is empty. 2. read list anywhere from 0 to infinite times. 3. Simultaneously write to the list anywhere from 0 to infinite times. <-- data race 4. jump to 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Race detector detects that you concurrently read and write the same address in memory.

It is by definition a data race.

It does not matter when data was actually put to that address (and whether it was put there at all). What only matters is that you access the same memory in different goroutines without synchronisation, and one of those operations is a "write".

Both are not about Go, but are extremely quality resources:

1. https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ - this and basically every other article in that blog is a gem.
2. http://deadlockempire.github.io/ - a puzzle-like game that reveals nuances of synchronisation and concurrency issues

Comment: Even if 1 hour is between writing the variable and reading it in different goroutines - race will be detected?

Comment: @Alexey race detector may have false negatives: it may not detect something. But yes, it still is a data race: if you don't synchronise the second goroutine is not guaranteed to ever see the changed values. The synchronisation happens by explicit CPU instructions (memory barriers) and has nothing to do with how long it passed between the operations.

Comment: Didn't expect that. So with goroutines every single variable must be synchronized?! And I thought only pointers like slices/maps are dangerous

Comment: @Alexey The thing is, if you start 2 goroutines, one creates a value (and stores it in a variable), the other sleeps 1 hour and attempts to read the value from variable, without synchronization, there is no guarantee the creation will happen before the read. The goroutine scheduler will do its best, but only synchronization gives guarantee, "nothing" else.

Comment: @icza, I see now. Just didn't expect. However, I'm sure Go will be able to do writing in 1 hour :)

Comment: @Alexey also see the update with couple useful links

Comment: @Alexey Yes, in practice the creation will not be delayed for an hour, but only synchronization gives guarantee. And race detector detects the lack of synchronization, the lack of guarantee.

Comment: It's not Go though: a CPU may decide to not synchronise caches. Go should cooperate with CPU, but CPU alone is free to do a lot of weird things

Comment: Probably last question, about the lack of guarantee to confirm - does this mean, that in my demo code I can get a situation, when the list already contains an `Object1`, but it's `object.A` is still `0`?

Comment: @Alexey I'd say any value might be there: imagine a situation when memory was already allocated but was not initialised yet.

Comment: You mean it could contain any bytes from previous object which was located at the same memory space?

Comment: @Alexey yep, why not. Most likely operations would not be reordered SO dramatically, but theoretically - why not :shrug:

Comment: My world was changed today, at least a little, thanks!

Comment: @Alexey check the Jeff Preshing's blog (#1 in the answer). A lot of articles there cover low level CPU & Memory interactions, it's a very entertaining reading.