# Safe to read from shared data structure in goroutines without channels

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and starting to use goroutines. I am curious if it is safe to read from a data structure that is being written to by another goroutines without using channel or mutex. In the example below, the `events` array is visible to main and goroutine, but main only reads from it and the goroutine is modifying it. Is this considered safe?

```
var events = []string{}

func main() {

    go func() {
        for {
            if len(events) > 30 {
                events = nil
            }
            event := "The time is now " + time.Now().String()
            events = append(events, event)
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 200)
        }
    }()

    for {
        for i:=0; i < len(events); i++ {
            fmt.Println(events[i])
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
        fmt.Println("--------------------------------------------------------")
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: No concurrent read + write is ever safe. Such code is racy and undefined under each and every condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is absolutely not safe. You should use synchronization primitives around access to `events`, or redesign to use channels.

Your code may work fine today, on a specific architecture/OS, but it may break unexpectedly with small changes and/or on another architecture/OS.

Try to run your code with `-race` to verify. You'll probably see `WARNING: DATA RACE`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153078/8206).

Comment: Thanks. You are right in that given the current state, no race conditions happen. But after thinking about it, I realized it could easily happen when main is looping over events and the memory address location could be invalid if my event list is long enough and a context switch happens during the loop.